# Not having @ in a field causes it to crash

Tags: c#

I'm having some trouble with some email validation.

I have two variables, email and emailTrim, email stores the users email address that they input, emailTrim, consists of the following code:

```
string emailTrim = email.Substring(0, email.LastIndexOf("@"));
```

This takes the email variable and removes everything after the @ symbol.
Which is exactly what I want it to do, however, that comes with the side affect of the error "ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled"

Could someone help me out with either an alternative way to remove everything after the '@' symbol, or a way to "handle" the exception thrown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Split()` instead:

```
string emailTrimmed = email.Split('@')[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `LastIndexOf` returns *some value* no matter what you pass, you should check the result to see if it is valid.

When the string has no `'@'` sign, `LastIndexOf` produces `-1`. Passing it to `Substring` gives you an invalid range from zero to negative 1.

Here is how you can fix this problem:

```
// Find the position of '@', and store it in a variable
var pos = email.LastIndexOf("@");
// Check the position for negative value before passing it to Substring
var emailTrim = pos >= 0 ? email.Substring(0, pos) : email;
```